# Best way to remove an adjoining circle in small logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

What is the recommended way to remove the "3" and circle it contains on this logo? The magic eraser/wand I didn't seem to fix it with. Any pros willing to assist?

[image]

Comment: Why dont you ask for the vector original? And is redrawing a solution for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I suck at drawing. Thanks! Would ideally like to do something in Photoshop.

Comment: **Best** way is to redraw it. It's merely a diamond shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This image is in very low resolution. I would almost call it pixel art. Editing logos like this isn't really the correct way. Normally you would have a vector file where you could just delete the unwanted objects and export a new PNG.

This said, it's pretty simple in Photoshop. Many ways to do it. This is a pretty hands on way which is only possible because of the pixelated and simple nature of the image.

- Optionally uncheck *View > Show > Smart Guides* so they don't interfere.
- Select the *Rectangular Marquee Tool* and make a selection which covers the unwanted part.
- Press <kbd>D</kbd> to reset to *Default Foreground and Background Colors* (in case they aren't already).
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> to fill the selection with black.
- Select the *Polygonal Lasso Tool* and make a selection which covers a part of the figure you can use to paint in the missing part.
- Select the *Move Tool*, hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag duplicates of the selected area to repair the missing part. Make sure to exactly follow the existing lines. Simple in this case, because they are all 45 degrees.

[image]

Comment: I'm not super experienced with PS so I was drawing a blank. This is really cool to learn, thanks Wolff!

Comment: I'm kinda unable to duplicate it as clean as that. The color of the blue part is lighter than yours too .. any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome @Bitter. Just remember that this is the simplest form of quick fixing an image. If you have a smarter workflow (like having the original vector file) you never have to do stuff like this. 

Comment: @Bitter, uhm hard to say ... do you perhaps have some *Feather* value applied? It's in the top, right below the menu. It should be set to 0. In this case you could also uncheck *Anti-alias* as you don't need that for such a simple operation. And make sure to select a few black pixels like I do. Don't try to make a selection that follows the shape perfectly.

Comment: Got it now, thanks man!